# Storing Facebook API data

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a web application that relies upon the Facebook API.  I want to use information retrieved about the users' friends, in order to display custom messages and updates to that user.  Standard Fare.

**I'm uncertain as to how long and in what manners I can store that information, specifically related to using a database**.

[Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) says under section II number 4 that

> A user's friends' data can only be used in the context of the user's
>   experience on your application.

Fine.  As for *storing*, section II number 2 states that

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data.

Does *cache* include database storage?  If so, does not having a 'right' to the data prohibit only the ways in which I can use that data, versus the length of time which I can store it?

Comment: I have a feeling this question will be closed as off-topic, but as far as I understand it, the answer to your question is that you should be fine to cache it, the data policies are primarily about prohibiting use of user data in ways that users would be surprised by (such as selling it to ad networks, etc)

Comment: It probably will since it's too 'policy' based.  But it certainly has an enormous impact on how the API can be used.  Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely store such data in your database. As stated in your second quote "you have no rights to this data", so you cannot sell or redistribute that data. You can however remix this data to improve "your application's user experience".

When the user authorises your app (i.e. connects with your app via Facebook) he allows your app to access his account. The most basic access provides you (the developer) with the user's list of friends as specified in [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). So essentially the user grants you permission to use that data. Additionally if you request some other friends-based permissions (e.g. `friends_activities`, `friends_checkins` explained in the same document) the user explicitly grants you permission to use that data. But obviously you can't share that information with 3rd parties.

I've been involved in many projects where we had to store information regarding a user's friends and it was always legally sound.

Also, there is no time limit on such storage.

Comment: How does this relate to research made on facebook? I mean, i'ts not specifically linked to the user experience, but in it's derived form, it could be linked to general user well-being, but that would probably be considered a stretch in UX terms.

Comment: @Jakob: That would be tricky. I'm sure you can do research based on that data but since it would be a "remix" of that data however since you have no rights to that data, your research becomes a derivative piece of work, so you have to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure when the 24 hour data storage policy was deprecated, but [Facebook data can now be stored indefinitely](https://www.facebook.com/help/100552270038780/)...

> **How long can I store data?**
>
> We have deprecated our 24 hour data storage policy. You may now
>   indefinitely cache data to improve your application's user experience.
>   Please refer to Section II of the Developer Principles and Policies
>   for more details on our data storage policies. You can learn more
>   about real time updates here.

Comment: Link is broken, and I can't find a substitute.  Hmm.  But good info! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the data, but you have to keep it updated.

> 4.If you cache data you receive from us, use it to improve your app’s user experience and keep it up to date.

Source: Developer Policy [Protect Data](https://developers.facebook.com/policy)