# Storing Facebook Data

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I know there have been numerous questions regarding Facebook's policies in which we can store information into our application's database. I have looked at [Storing Facebook API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519433/storing-facebook-api-data) and also have looked at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ but I just want to ensure that I am not violating Facebook's terms of use. I want to store a user's objectID in order to get certain information about them for use on another screen on my application (namely their profile picture) into my database. I was wondering, is that considered okay? I have looked around and haven't seen anything explicitly speaking about storing a user's objectID so I just wanted to confirm this would be okay. If this is not okay, would any one have any suggestions on how I can get a specific user's profile picture? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe for Facebook's API things like a user's object ID is actually just an ID for that user for specifically your application. Meaning, you have a unique ID for a user that is completely different than the ID that Facebook uses internally or that another application has for the same user. So unless I terribly misunderstand, you can and should store that.